# How to get Route in Middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Currently I can get a route in a controller by injecting it into the method I want to use it in.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(Route $route)
    {
        echo $route->getActionName();
    }
}
```

However I'm trying to perform something similar in middleware but can't get it going.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

class SetView implements Middleware {

    protected $route;

    public function __construct(Route $route)
    {
        $this->route = $route;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        echo $this->route->getActionName();

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Getting an error.

```
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $methods ]] in class Illuminate\Routing\Route
```

Not really sure what to do with that. Don't really care if it's a route or not, but need to get that action name somehow.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Remove your constructor/put it to default like;

```
public function __construct(){}
```

Try accessing the route via the handle method like so;

```
 $request->route();
```

So you should be able to access the action name like so;

```
 $request->route()->getActionName();
```

If the route return is null be sure you have registered the middleware within the App/Http/Kernel.php, like so;

```
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    'Path\To\Middleware',
];
```

**The above is for global middleware**

For route specific filtering place the `'Path\To\Middleware',` within the middleware array within RouteServiceProvider.php within the `App\Providers` folder.

You can also access the route object via `app()->router->getCurrentRoute()`.

**Edit:**

You could possibly try the following;

```
$route = Route::getRoutes()->match($request);
$route->getActionName();
```

This get the route from the `RouteCollection`. Be sure to encapsulate this within a try catch as this will throw a `NotFoundHttpException`.

Comment: Not working, complains about namespace, so I made it `\Route::current()` but it's a big object, not sure how to pull anything out of there as `getActionName()` throws an error. Also strange, even though I can set properties in the `__construct`, when I set `$this->route = \Route::current()` in the construct and `print_r` in the `handle` func nothing shows up. Although if I `print_r` in the `__construct` I get the big object printing out.

Comment: Still nodda, `$request->route()` just comes back as `null`.

Comment: Have you added your middleware into the App/Http/Kernal middleware array variable or within the RouteServiceProvider? As this could be the cause of the null on the $request->route().

Comment: You would also try accessing it via app()->router->getCurrentRoute()->getActionName()

Comment: Works in the RouteServiceProvider, which is fine for now, thanks :-)

Comment: Updated the answer to include the extra content.

Comment: i wanna do the same thing but, i need to get the action name from the my middleware not from any other place. this answer didn't work for me, it always return `null`.

Comment: You do know the return from `$request->route()` is either a `Route` object or  `null` so it is not entirely incorrect. If the middleware is being called before the route is called itself, there is no `Route` to get the name from.

Comment: NOT WORKING DEAR, getting error - Call to a member function getAction() on null (500 Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 13):

For Laravel 5.1.x

In your global middleware

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

$route = Route::getRoutes()->match($request);
$currentroute = $route->getName();
```

Comment: The only issue with this solution is the inefficient overhead of matching the route twice on every request (because the mainline router has to match it afterwards anyway).

Comment: Getting error `Call to a member function match() on array (500 Internal Server Error)`