# Laravel 5.1 route name resource null - Route::currentRouteName()

Tags: routes, middleware, laravel-5.1

I noted that there are several similar topics, however none of the solutions have solved my problem.

Setting up my route this so as follows:

```
Route::resource('clientes', 'Clients\ClientsController',
    [
        'names' => [
                        'create'    => 'clients.create',
                        'store'     => 'clients.store',
                        'edit'      => 'clients.edit',
                        'update'    => 'clients.update'
                    ]
    ]
);
```

I have to catch the route name in Middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    var_dump(Route::currentRouteName());exit;
}
```

The methods create and edit print:

```
string(14) "clients.create"

string(12) "clients.edit"
```

However, the methods store and update print NULL.

Other method we tried were:

```
$request->route()->getName();

app()->router->getCurrentRoute()->getName();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this :

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
```

or if u need action name

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName();

//OR 

$request->route()->getActionName();
```

Source : **[Illuminate/Routing/Router](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html)**.

Take a look at **[How to get Route in Middleware in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887666/how-to-get-route-in-middleware-in-laravel)**.

Hope that this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I did it relative to the `Route::currentRouteName()` by doing

```
// Prefix name, i.e. Interfaces
$getPrefix = preg_replace ("/\W|\./", '', $request-> route ()-> getPrefix ());
// Full route name if controller resource, unless it'd be only controller name
$getName = $request-> route ()-> getName ();
// Resource action name, or another
$getActionName = $request-> route ()-> getActionName ();
// Full route name
echo $route = $getActionName === "Closure" ? "{$getPrefix}.{$getName}.index" : $getName;
```

Thus I don't need to make any namespace for [Router](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html), so I may use the [Request](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html)'s [route](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html) like a charm.