# Laravel feature test using middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-testing

I'm trying to make a feature test for the start page of my Laravel application.

**Route:**

```
Route::domain('{subdominio}.'.env("APP_DOMAIN"))->middleware('mapNumserie')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'FarmaciaController@show')->middleware('modomtofarmacia')->name('inicio');
})
```

For some reasons, I use a **middleware** `mapNumserie` where I map the subdomain aganist a serial number `$idfarmacia` in order to use it after in controller:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    try{
        $route = $request->route();
        $idfarmacia = \App\Farmacia::where('subdominio', $route->subdominio)->value('numserie');
        $route->setParameter('idFarmacia', $idfarmacia);
        $route->forgetParameter('subdominio');
    }
    catch (\Exception $e){
        abort(404);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

In my `ModoMtoFarmacia` middleware I just check that an app instance is not in maintenance mode or disabled:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
        $farmacia = \App\Farmacia::find($request->idFarmacia);
        if($farmacia->inactiva){
            abort(404);
        }
        if(!$farmacia->modomantenimiento){
            return $next($request);
        }
        else{
            return response()->view('errors.503')->setStatusCode(503);
        }
    }
```

In my **controller** symply get some data using this `$idfarmacia` and return a view:

```
public function show(Request $request, $idfarmacia) {
    $data = 
        //Query...
    if($data){
        return view('inicio', ['data' => $data]);
    }
    else{
        abort(404);
    }

}
```

With a very simple **test** method I hope to validate a 200 response :

```
public function test_example(){
    $response = $this->get('http://mysubdomain.domain.prj');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

But when I **run** the test I get:

```
Expected response status code [200] but received 404.
```

The used URL works correctly in web environment, but the test fails. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You could debug in your code, before your condition, to check if $idfarmacia is not empty, and/or debug the process in the Middleware

Comment: Ok, I did it. $route = $request->route() gets '/' value in middleware. I don't know the reason.

Comment: How should I buld the route? Or how should I build the test to verify that route?

Comment: I tested your middleware "mapNumserie" and I have "/" all the time. I don't understand how it works. I think I am missing some information

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887666/how-to-get-route-in-middleware-in-laravel

Comment: Thanks for your time. As I said, if I debug the same request launched from the browser, the $route variable takes the appropriate value, being the same use case as in the test

Comment: To ensure you are hitting the correct url, what does route('inicio', ['subdominio' => 'mydomain']); give you in php artisan tinker?

Comment: Your code works for me, in browser and in test. I however had to modify env ("...") in config::get("...") because I use "artisan config:cache"

Comment: route('inicio', ['subdominio' => 'mydomain']); in artisan tinker returns "http://mysubdomain.domain.prj"

Comment: instead of hard coding the url in the test can you replace it with route('inicio', ['subdominio' => 'mydomain']) and see if the variables are set then

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it but the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a found the problem in my `phpunit.xml` settings, which caused an error in the first query (also in any other), in this case the one found in the MapNumserie middleware:

```
 $idfarmacia = \App\Farmacia::where('subdominio', $route->subdominio)->value('numserie');
```

I had to set up properly the values of `DB_DATABASE` and `DB_CONNECTION`